# Shape-shifting outcast female who is forced to leave her village?

Tags: story-identification, shape-shifter

I can't for the life of me remember the title of this book.  There is an outcast female who is not like the others of her village (who reside in a crevice) she can shape-shifting into multiple different forms and when she has to leave everything she knows.  I believe this is a series with the girl going to a seaside cliff type village next.

Comment: When did you read it? Roughly how long ago was it published? What language was it in? Can you describe anything about the book cover?

Comment: The Chronicles of Mavin Manyshaped by Sheri S. Tepper might be worth having a look at.

Comment: @DafyddNZ it seems very likely this is The Song of Mavin Manyshaped. Are you going to post that as an answer?

Comment: Hi Tammy. If you're remembering the _Mavin Manyshaped_ books she flees the village with her brother _Mertyn_ to escape being gang raped by the village elders. In the second book _Mavin_ goes to a village built on the side of the cliff and occupied by people called _Birders_.

Answer (score 4):

[The Chronicles of Mavin Manyshaped](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41032-the-chronicles-of-mavin-manyshaped) a trilogy by Sheri S. Tepper consists of three books The Song of Mavin Manyshaped, The Flight of Mavin Manyshaped, and The Search of Mavin Manyshaped, it has also been released as an omnibus.

In the world of The True Game shapeshifters usually only have 2-3 shapes they can assume, Mavin is called manyshaped as she can seemingly take on any shape.

The Song of Mavin Manyshaped tells of her escaping from her village with her younger brother after reaching adolescence.